# Sql server Varchar DateTime Column add Day to Date how to?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a Varchar Datetime Column on a SQL Server.
I need add 5 day to User Last Date.

I tried

```
" UPDATE [dbo].[infoTbl] SET lastDate convert(DATEADD (dd, 5, lastDate)) "
" UPDATE [dbo].[infoTbl] SET lastDate DATEADD (dd, 5, lastDate) "
" UPDATE [dbo].[infoTbl] SET lastDate convert(DATEADD (d, 5, CAST(@lastDate AS datetime)) AS varchar(10)) "
```

Error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

my old date value is : `20.09.2015 10:14`
i re build database on Godaddy, new value is :
 `2015-09-15 04:52:52.723`

Comment: `UPDATE [dbo].[infoTbl] SET lastDate= cast(DATEADD(d, 5, CAST(@lastDate AS datetime)) as nvarchar(22))`

Comment: @tinka, would you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: is the character representation dd.mm.yyyy hh:mi ? If so we can not simply CAST to DATETIME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this is why you should use appropriate data types.

To use any DATETIME function you would need to convert the value to DATE/Datetime and then use the function and then convert it back to varchar to update the column.

Something like.......

```
UPDATE [dbo].[infoTbl] 
  SET lastDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), 
                          DATEADD (DAY
                                   ,5
                                   , CAST( SUBSTRING(lastDate , 7, 4) 
                                    +SUBSTRING(lastDate , 4, 2)
                                    +LEFT(lastDate ,2) 
                                    +' ' +RIGHT(lastDate, 5)  AS DateTime)
                                   ), 121)
WHERE ISDATE(  SUBSTRING(lastDate , 7, 4) 
             + SUBSTRING(lastDate , 4, 2)
             + LEFT(lastDate ,2) 
             +' ' +RIGHT(lastDate, 5))     = 1
```

Comment: "i have Additional information: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." Error too

Comment: you are trying to put a lisptick on a pig, you need to fix the actual problem here, you should never store dates in varchar, use date/datetime data type for your column. for now you can add a where clause to only affect valid datetime values.

Comment: Yeah i know, but this database is old and need very code change.

Comment: To be more precise if sample datetime is '20.09.2015 10:14' , the CAST fails because it is in dd/mm/yyyy not mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Yes my date value is 20.09.2015 10:14 .  I have a vb.net application, i don't use your script sorry.

Comment: Ohhhh sorry, I re build my database on a Godaddy. my old date value 20.09.2015 but new records value is 2015-09-15 04:52:52.723 :/

Comment: M.Ali great work your script. is it possible dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm format?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following script

```
declare @chardate varchar(30) = '10.09.2015 10:14'
declare @datetime datetime
set @datetime = convert(datetime, substring(@chardate,1,10),104) + convert(datetime, substring(@chardate,12,5),108)
select dateadd(dd,5,@datetime)
```

While converting character datetime representation to a datetime variable, you can use [CONVERT function with Datetime Format options](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-format-date-format-datetime-t-sql-convert-function.aspx)

You can find the 104, 108 formatting options at given reference
Unfortunately, your character representation does not match with a basic format, so I had to seperate date and time